# Django - Filter a queryset by a property value

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter a queryset by the field id which is in an array of objects. I already have the id to compare this field to ie request.user.id which I get from the authenticated user.
Lets assume that the logged in user has an id = 290 Thus;

```
request.user.id = 290
```

Below is the structure of the Queryset

```
[
   {
      "id":"93b9f61a-a5c9-4c26-99a4-22f5447bdd3f",
      "approval_status":"not approved",
      "assignee":[
         {
            "id":289,
            "username":"zverifier"
         }
      ],
      "sector":"Electricity"
   },
   {
      "id":"270387f6-3c5c-4289-8baa-08441f318ec1",
      "approval_status":"approved",
      "assignee":[
         {
            "id":289,
            "username":"zverifier"
         },
         {
            "id":290,
            "username":"yverifier"
         }
      ],
      "sector":"Electricity"
   }
]
```

I have tried using this;

```
queryset = queryset.filter(assignee=request.user.id)
```

but it only stops at the assignee and cant proceed to the id field within assignee.At the end of the day, I would like the Authenticated user to only see objects in which he is an assignee.

The model for the report is here;

```
class Report(TimestampedModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)  
    approval_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default='NOT_ACTIONED')
    assignee = models.ManyToManyField(AppUser, blank=True, verbose_name='assignee', related_name='report_assignees')
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

The model for the User is here;

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default='SYSTEM')
    cso = models.ForeignKey(Cso, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In the queryset I provided above, theres only some field for the user I provided, just to be brief, but in actual sense it returns all the user related data

Comment: You seem to be showing a serialized representation of your data (Along with related models). Please show your _model_ instead. Is `assignee` a m2m or a foreign key from the other model?

Comment: You probably need something like this: `queryset = queryset.filter(assignee__contains={'id': request.user.id, username: request.user.username})`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#contains

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I tried that method and i get ; Related Field got invalid lookup: contains as an error. it seems like am not allowed to use contains on assignee

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added the models and assignee is m2m relationship as you'll see in the model

Comment: Do you mean that when you are filtering you get the `Report` instances having the related `AppUser` instance as you want but it also shows other `AppUser` and you don't want that?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not that but I want to return report instances to the appuser if his data is in assignee